# How to Call NSUserDefault Value To Another View Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

// I wrote this function in Separate class file:

```
-(void)Display
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger *Position = [prefs integerForKey:@"currentlevel"];
    NSLog(@"------->%i",Position);
    //This NSLog is returning Value 6  
    [prefs synchronize];    
}
```

//In my `viewController` I am calling this function using object I have created for my class

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    //display My class name
    //disp is object fro my class
    display *disp;   
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    disp = [[display alloc]init];  
    [disp Display];
    NSLog(@"%i",[disp Position]);
    //this NSLog statement returning value 0
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If anyone has any solution please help me.

Comment: You should make an utility class just for its class methods. What you are doing is wrong in many ways.

Comment: What is `Position`? Is it a local variable? a property? a method?

Comment: A solution to what? I don't see a question. I do see you didn't show your code for the method `Position` which is pretty important to understand your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498213/how-to-implement-nsuserdefault-to-access-through-multiple-views

Comment: @Amar Position is my Global Variable property and i synthesized it in my implementation file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement like this..

```
@implementation ClassA

      - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:100 forKey:@"currentlevel"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

    @end

    @implementation ClassB

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
           int B = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentlevel"] integerValue];

         NSLog(@"Interger Value %d",b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the value from NSUserDefaults in the view controller itself? Like this:

```
    -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSInteger *Position = [prefs integerForKey:@"currentlevel"];
      NSLog(@"------->%i",Position);
    }
```

Comment: I want to fallow MVC pattern so i created separate class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an integer value then use this statement:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"kHighScore"];
```

If you want to get that value back then use this statement:

```
NSInteger highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kHighScore"] intValue];
```